# Redirect to the folder you came from

Tags: html, redirect, href

I have two same forms (duplicates) in different folders since each folder can be accessed by selected group of people. Now I want to get rid of duplicate and just keep one file. However, I want this file to be able to find out from which folder the user accessed the file and redirect back to the folder he came from at the end of successful submission.

Any ideas?

Comment: show your form code.  Also, show how you direct to the file\folder.  Maybe jsfiddle it.

Comment: form is simple html. i was using this to redirect   <INPUT value="http://www.domain.com" type=hidden name=redirect>. I want to see the referrer and at the end, redirect to the referrer. I think this will solve the question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to add a hidden field to the form for the referring page:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="referrer" />
```

This can then either be set using any server side code, or with javascript when the page with the form on loads:

```
document.getElementById('referrer').value = escape(document.referrer);
```

Comment: for some reason it did not work. does it supposed to dynamically change the value and put the referring page?